# How to disable CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE in django

Tags: django, cookies, csrf

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

My frontend and backend run on different domains in development, I'm trying to enable setting csrf-token cookie using HTTP, but I guess `False` value for CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE option somehow gets interpreted as 'not set' and Chrome says

[image]

My second guess is that it *has to* be `True`, otherwise it's not allowed to send cookies between domains. So my question is whether it's possible to set cookies via plain HTTP with cross-domain requests and if it is, what are the right Django settings for achieving this

Comment: Did you already try it with `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` within settings.py? I feel like if you set your multiple domains there as trusted it should do the trick..

Comment: yes, CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS is fine, because if I remove it, then another error appears